# wikidata sparql query using string

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I would like to query wikidata in order to obtain entries based_on some technologies (blockchain, solid, RDF and so on). These potential technologies would change dynamically, so that, I inject them as literals from a piece of code. The point is that I get no results when trying injecting literals (strings).

In the next piece of SPARQL, you can see five different approaches I tried (all of them fail), through https://query.wikidata.org/

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX xsd: <www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?item 
WHERE { 
#test1    ?item wdt:P144 ?o FILTER (str(?o) = 'blockchain' ) .
#test2    ?item wdt:P144 ?o FILTER (regex (?o,'blockchain')) .
#test3    ?item wdt:P144 ?o FILTER (regex (?o,'^blockchain$')) .
#test4    ?item wdt:P144 'blockchain'  .
#test5    ?item wdt:P144 "blockchain"  .
}
```

Any clue? 
Thx in advance for your time and support.

Comment: the values of `wdt:P144` are Wikidata entites, thus, the values of `?o` are URIs like `wd:123` or whatever. It's obvious that a string filter on those URIs doesn't match

Comment: `SELECT ?item 
WHERE { 
?item wdt:P144 ?o . ?o rdfs:label ?ol 
                                FILTER (lang(?ol) = 'en')
                                        FILTER(contains(str(?ol),'blockchain' ))}`

Comment: alternative with entity search API: `SELECT ?item WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "blockchain" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .
      ?o wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
      ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true .
  }
  ?item wdt:P144 ?o
} ORDER BY ASC(?num) LIMIT 20`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @AKSW. 
It make full sense. Do you get a blog, or youtube channel where follwing you